# Can't open NerdDinner project in vs2008

Tags: nerddinner

NerdDinner.csproj won't load in vs2008 sp1 with .net 3.5 sp1. Am I not up-to-date on these tools or something? It complains this project type not supported on this installation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you have the ASP.NET MVC Framework installed? If not, you need it. NerdDinner is an example of an MVC Framework project, and you won't be able to open it or run it without the ASP.NET MVC Framework installed.

You can find the appropriate installation information at http://www.asp.net or more specifically http://www.asp.net/mvc

Comment: Right, that's all it was. I thought I had installed it before.

Answer (score 1):

In my I had to change the value of the "ProjectTypeGuids" in the project file. I copied them from another MVC project that I had created with my version of VS 2008.

This is the post that gave me the answer:

http://www.stuffthatjustworks.com/How+To+Fix+Xcsproj+Cannot+Be+Opened+The+Project+Type+Is+Not+Supported+By+This+Installation.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In my case...it was the wrong version of the framework.

I just copied the  from another asp.net mvc project I had made.  (then you probably have to fix up the references, which is trivial with resharper :-) )