# Cant open Nerd Dinner 1.0 VS 2008 SP1 MVC 2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I was trying to download some ASP.NET MVC Sample application to learn MVC. I tried Music Store and TownHall but they wont open in my VS2008.So I tried the common Nerddinner 1.0 but it gives error "The project Type is not supported by this installation" . I tried the 3rd Method suggested in the following post

[Can't open NerdDinner project in vs2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002907/cant-open-nerddinner-project-in-vs2008)

This is about changing the project type GUIDS.Now the project loads but when I run it throws an exception

```
<add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0,     Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

I presume this is happening because the Nerddinner 1.0 is for MVC 1.0 and I have MVC 2.0 installed. How do I proceed now. I have spent a lot of time trying to get an MVC application working on my PC. I am happy if I can get any properly architected , MVC application of medium to high complexity to work on my PC.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the free [MVC project upgrade tool](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2010/03/10/migrating-asp-net-mvc-1-0-applications-to-asp-net-mvc-2-rtm.aspx) that I wrote a while ago. Download it, run it, and point it at your NerdDinner solution. It will convert the project from MVC 1.0 to MVC 2.

Other random notes:

- MVC 1.0 and MVC 2 are side-by-side compatible.
- There is a built-in upgrade wizard in Visual Studio 2010 that will convert MVC 1.0 VS2008 projects to MVC 2 VS2010 projects.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after reloading a new dev machine a few months ago.  I *think* I was still able to install MVC v1 side by side to fix...